# Efficient way to extract individual bit values from a hexa string

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I'm developing a real-time application where I have to process a line of data as fast as possible to send it over to an app. These lines arrive at a very fast rate, around 40k per minute. The task is to extract the value of certain individual bits from the hexa data in the line. I have a solution already but I doubt it's the most efficient one, so I'm asking if you can improve it.

A sample line of data:

```
p1                p2      p3     len  data
1497383697        0120    000    5    00 30 63 4f 15
```

*len* is how many bytes are in the data, *data* is what we're working with. Let's say I want to extract 3 bits starting from the 11th from the left. Converting the hexa to binary with padding:
0x0030634f15 = 0000 0000 00**11 0**000 0110 0011 0100 1111 0001 0101
The wanted value is 0b110 which is 6 in decimal.

My working solution for the problem is this:

```
# 11 and 3 in the example
start = config.getint(p, 'start') 
length = config.getint(p, 'length')

parts = line.split()
hexadata = ''.join(parts[4:])
bindata = bin(int(hexadata, 16))[2:].zfill(len(hexadata) * 4)
val = int(bindata[start:start + length], 2)
```

*val* will hold the value 6 in the end. Any other, more efficent way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Your code outputs 4 instead of 6. That's if I set `line = "1497383697        0120    000    5    00 30 63 4f 15"` and `start = 11` and `length = 3`.

Comment: The 3 digits you highlighted actually start at index 10, not 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using string operations, it's faster to convert the input to a number and use bit operations:

```
parts = line.split(maxsplit=4)

# remove spaces in the number and convert it to int from base 16
num = int(parts[4].replace(' ', ''), 16)

# create a bit mask with exactly `length` 1s
mask = (1 << length) - 1

# calculate the offset from the right
shift = 40 - start - length

# shift the value to the right and apply the binary mask to get our value
val = (num >> shift) & mask
```

---

According to my timings, the bit operations are faster by about 20%. Timing results with 1 million iterations:

```
string_ops  2.735653492003621 seconds
bit_ops     2.190693126998667 seconds
```

Comment: Suggest saving some operations by replacing the last two lines with `val = (num >> shift) & mask`.

Comment: @TimPeters Good thinking! Will update as soon as I'm done timing it, thanks.